# Spring security jwt token 403 error when trying to access a resource

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

JwtRequestFilter:

```
package com.rest.app.filters;


import com.rest.app.services.MyUserDetailsService;
import com.rest.app.util.JwtUtil;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetailsSource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;


@Component
public class JwtRequestFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Autowired
    private MyUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private JwtUtil jwtUtil;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        final String authorizationHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");

        System.out.println(authorizationHeader);

        String userName = null;
        String jwt = null;

        if (authorizationHeader != null && authorizationHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            jwt = authorizationHeader.substring(7);
            userName = jwtUtil.extractUserName(jwt);
        }


        if (userName != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() != null) {
            UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(userName);
            if (jwtUtil.validateToken(jwt, userDetails)) {
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken =
                        new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
                        .setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);
            }
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

App:

```
package com.rest.app;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@SpringBootApplication
public class RestApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(RestApplication.class, args);
    }


    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**")
                        .allowedOrigins("*")
                        .allowedMethods("GET", "PUT", "POST", "PATCH", "DELETE", "OPTIONS")
                        .allowedHeaders("*");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

SecurityConfigurer:

```
package com.rest.app.configuration;


import com.rest.app.filters.JwtRequestFilter;
import com.rest.app.services.MyUserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.NoOpPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;


@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfigurer extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private MyUserDetailsService myUserDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private JwtRequestFilter jwtRequestFilter;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(myUserDetailsService);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/authenticate", "/user/create", "/user/login").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        http.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
    }


    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }






}
```

I'm still getting this:

```
"timestamp":"2021-08-08T15:23:52.656+00:00","status":403,"error":"Forbidden","path":"/api/user/account/deposit"}
```

Response Headers:

```
Vary: origin
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Sun, 08 Aug 2021 15:37:25 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=60
Connection: keep-alive
```

Request Headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Sun, 08 Aug 2021 15:23:52 GMT
Expires: 0
Keep-Alive: timeout=60
Pragma: no-cache
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Vary: Origin
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: pl-PL,pl;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJtYXJlazEyMyIsImV4cCI6MTYyODQ3MjE5MiwiaWF0IjoxNjI4NDM2MTkyfQ.rxUQ3uzCTtriMUkrKCayBDCQ4Q4aXTHD_z-R7A8Oduc
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 2
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Host: localhost:8080
Origin: http://localhost:3000
Referer: http://localhost:3000/
sec-ch-ua: "Opera";v="77", "Chromium";v="91", ";Not A Brand";v="99"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.164 Safari/537.36 OPR/77.0.4054.277
{}
```

I can't get this resource, even though i am sending jwt token in the authorization request header.
OPTIONS request gets through with no problems with the status code 200. Is it about my jwt authorization or my CORS configuration? I'm using spring security. I have tried all the solutions i could find.

Comment: And your debug logs are saying?

Comment: Also writing a custom jwt filter is bad practice, spring security has had full jwt support for 3 years now, please read the chapter in the spring security reference documentation.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I found the reason, in my JwtRequestFilter, instead of this:

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() != null
```

It should be this:

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null
```